# Matching URLs with normalisation/canonicalisation

Tags: php, url, canonicalization

I found this solution to normalise and match equal URLs but I want to know if there is anything more elegant, doesn't PHP have a URL normalising function?

```
function urlMatch($url1, $url2)
{
    // parse the urls
    $r1 = parse_url($url1);
    $r2 = parse_url($url2);

    // get the variables out of the queries
    parse_str($r1['query'], $v1);
    parse_str($r2['query'], $v2);

    // match the domains and paths
    if ($r1['host'] != $r2['host'] || $r1['path'] != $r2['path'])
        return false;

    // match the arrays
    foreach ($v1 as $key => $value)
        if (array_key_exists($key, $v2) && $value != $v2[$key])
            return false;

    // if we haven't returned already, then the queries match
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Retagged to add canonicalization and remove normalization.  In the context of SO, the 'normalization' tag refers to database normalization.  Canonicalization is more likely to attract the right type of expert.

Comment: This function is wrong! What about `schema` and `port`? Or additional arguments existing only in second url?

Comment: I guess I need something more elegant and correct now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be more suitable for your needs:

```
function urlMatch($url1, $url2){
  // parse the urls
  $r1 = parse_url($url1);
  $r2 = parse_url($url2);

  if (isset($r1['query'])){
    // get the variables out of the query
    parse_str($r1['query'], $v1);
    // sort arguments so they be in exactly same order
    asort($v1);
    // place sorted arguments back
    $r1['query'] = http_build_query($v1);
  }

  if (isset($r2['query'])){
    parse_str($r2['query'], $v2);
    asort($v2);
    $r2['query'] = http_build_query($v2);
  }

  // Match re-constructed urls (you'll need pecl_http extension for this)
  $matched = http_build_url($r1) === http_build_url($r2);

  return $matched;
}
```

**Update:** I've changed code a bit to deal with empty queries...